# jQuery addClass when an input element is focused on

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I can't get this jquery to add a class when an input element is focused on.

```
(function($) {

$('input.input-text').focus( function(){
    $(this).parent('p').addClass('focused_on');
});

});
```

Its supposed to add the 'focused_on' class to the parent p element when the input gets focused on.

Here is the HTML:

```js
(function($) {

  $('input.input-text').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent('p').addClass('focused_on');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field"><label for="billing_first_name" class="">First 
    Name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" autocomplete="given-name" value="" /></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a trailing space in the class attribute of your input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper function isn't being called. Look at this:

```
(function($) {

});
```

This defines an anonymous function, but doesn't run it. In order to run a function, you need the `()`, and since you're passing in jQuery, you need to do this:

```
(function ($) {

})(jQuery); // runs function, and passes in jQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end line do this 
    })(jquery);

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'p'` from `.parent()`
I checked. All work

And add `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

$('input.input-text').focus( function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('focused_on');
});

});
```